# couldn't post and insert to database and echo result AJAX/PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm current try to use ajax autosave the data after the timeout, but I'm having an error that the data seem didn't execute, I checked my database and no record is added.

Below is my code:

```
<?php $userDate = implode('-', array($year,$month,$day)); ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        #success {
            display: none;
            font-family: Arial;
            color: green;
            margin-left: 85px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type    : 'POST',
                    url     : 'log.php',
                    data    : {userDob: '<?php echo $userDate; ?>'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        if (data.success){
                            $('#success').fadeIn(1000).append('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
                        }
                    }
               });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="success"></div>
```

I view the source and the `data` show the correct variable as per the result, example: `$day = 26, $month = 12, $year = 1976` and the result show is `data: {userDob: 1976-12-26}`

And my log.php

```
<?php
require('../inc/connection.php');
$dob = $_POST['userDob'];
//Create log file to count daily customer visit
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log (dob, log_datetime, log_count, amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $dob);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $now, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $cust_count);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $amount);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$cust_count = 1;
$amount = 10;
$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode(array('success'=>TRUE,'message'=>"Record Added"));

?>
```

May I know where did I go wrong and causing the data didn't insert to the database and echo the result within the same page?

Comment: Use `errorInfo` to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            timeout     :5000,
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'log.php',
            data    : {date:'<?php echo $userDate; ?>'},
            dataType    : 'json',
            success     : function(data) {      
                if (data.success){
                    $('#success').fadeIn(1000).append('<p>' + data.posted + '</p>');
                }
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not working, the data didn't posted and database didn't capture the record